# flutter apk still saving SharedPreferences value data

Tags: android, flutter, dart

when i rebuild apk in Android Studio or vs code and send this apk by WhatsApp to test still saves SharedPreferences value data  It causes some problems

Notice: that's not fris time send this apk to the same phone .

this is my cahsHelper calss

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class CahsHelper {
  static SharedPreferences? sharedPreferences;

  static cashInit() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static Future<bool> saveDataCashHelper(
      {required String key, required dynamic value}) async {
    if (value is String) return await sharedPreferences!.setString(key, value);
    if (value is bool) return await sharedPreferences!.setBool(key, value);
    if (value is int) return await sharedPreferences!.setInt(key, value);
    return await sharedPreferences!.setDouble(key, value);
  }

  static dynamic getDataCashHelper({required String key}) {
    return sharedPreferences!.get(key);
  }

  static Future<bool> clearCash({
    required String key,
  }) async {
    return await sharedPreferences!.remove(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid this behavior during testing, you have a few options:

**1. Uninstall the old app.**
You can avoid persisting old data by uninstalling the old app before reinstalling it.

**2. Clear Data Manually**
On the testing device, go to the device's "Settings" -> "Apps" -> [Your App] -> "Storage" -> "Clear Data". This will remove all app data, including SharedPreferences data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).